# Show Error Phrase in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer

I have a small script that create a new Customer in Magento 2 and used to work but sudenly, it does not.

I included a try...catch but do not know how to show the error message in console. I want to be able to return the error phare:

```
try {

        $this->_customerRepository->save($this->_customerObject);
        $this->answer = array('response' => true);

    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\State\InputMismatchException $ex) {
        $this->answer = array('response' => 'Email exists');
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException $ex) {
        $this->answer = array('response' => 'bad input', 'ex' => $ex->getErrors());
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $ex) {
        $this->answer = array('response' => 'No idea....');
    }
```

The Exception arised is **InputException**, and want to return the phrase in the response, because i do not know where is the fault.

getErrors() only return an object and can not see the error message in console.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getErrors() returns an array of LocalizedException: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Exception/AbstractAggregateException.php#L90

To get the actual message you shoul call getRawMessage(): https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Exception/LocalizedException.php#L42

this should return a helpfull message